# does yammer have a bookmarklet version sharing button?

Tags: bookmarklet, yammer

Does yammer have a Bookmarklet for sharing web pages from the browser's bookmarks bar?

Facebook has a sharing Bookmarklet available as noted at https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10100335789861533.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the Web Applications StackExchange site.

Comment: A web search turned up https://www.yammer.com/messages/new#/Messages/bookmarklet. It's also used for https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button.